# Flutter_native_splash didn't work for Android but it did for iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, native, splash-screen

I Used **flutter_native_splash** to display a splash screen with my image. It didn't work for Android, but it did work for iOS. I followed the video tutorial recommended on the **flutter_native_splash** pub.dev page and everything looks right.

Are there any Android specific settings that might be stopping the splash screen from displaying. Or anything else I should check?

Comment: what android version do you have? is it 12+ ? if yes you may see the note on the documentation https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#android-12-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used android/ios/web properties in pubspec?
Try setting them to true for each platform you need.

Also, provide your code so we can have a look at it and debug.

And as @[pmmatatias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12838877/pmatatias) said, it might be a version specific issue as well, do check debug device Android version.